# In where condition split with comma separated string values

Tags: sql-server

How to pass a comma separated text to a where condition. I have a query scenario like below

```
select *
from employees
where employeeid in ('PER5AZ,SF4MDD,WQERR') -- This will not work
```

Here I need to filter the `employeeid` by PER5AZ, SF4MDD and WQERR which I get as a comma separated string from front end.

How to do this in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: You may use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the input text.

Comment: do you have a sample query as i need to pass this on where condition. like select *
from employees
where employeeid in ('PER5AZ,SF4MDD,WQERR')

Comment: You may try with `select * from employees where employeeid in (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT('PER5AZ,SF4MDD,WQERR', ','))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this using STRING_SPLIT function.

```
select *
from employees
where employeeid in (select value from STRING_SPLIT ('PER5AZ,SF4MDD,WQERR', ','))
```

*Note: STRING_SPLIT works SQL server 2016 or above*